# Best Security Magazines and Websites

Tags: security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stay up-to-date on computer (especially software) security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111248/how-can-i-stay-up-to-date-on-computer-especially-software-security)

I want to ask about some good security magazines and websites that keep me in touch with the latest computer security issues which I am interested in as a programmer (news, articles, tools,internet security, Hacking and Defence...etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great site for IT security is [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page):

> The Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) is a 501c3 not-for-profit worldwide charitable organization focused on improving the security of application software.